# why constractor of java class not work on android?

Tags: java, android, constructor

in java when we use for loop and make new object from class constractor method of class is run 5 times for example:
 for (int x=0; x<5; x++) {c1 = new CountTest();}

in android it is not work correctly!!!
this is the code:

```
package com.hamid.counttestapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(Counter()));
    }


    public int Counter()
    {
        CountTest c1 = new CountTest();
        for (int x=0; x<5; x++) {
            c1 = new CountTest();
        }
        return c1.getInstanceCount();
    }

    class CountTest
    {
        private int instanceCount = 0;

        public CountTest()
        {
            instanceCount++;
        }

        public int getInstanceCount()
        {
            return instanceCount;
        }
    }
}
```

the constractor should run 4 times and value of instanceCount shoulde be 4.
but number 4 not see in the textview.
textview show number: 1

it means constractor not run 5 times correctly.
whats wrong..?

Comment: "_value of instanceCount shoulde be 4_" Why do you think this is the case? `instanceCount` is an instance variable so each instance gets its own.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is executed 5 times, and 5 `CountTest` instances are created.

However, since `instanceCount` is an instance variable, each of the 5 instances of `CountTest` class has a different copy of that variable. All of them are initialized to 0 and then incremented to 1.

If you make it a `static` variable, you'll get your expected output. All the instance of the `CountTest` class would update the same variable.

Change

```
private int instanceCount = 0;
```

to

```
private static int instanceCount = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i change the line ..  in Java it is correct  but in android i see error massage : Inner classes cannot have static declarations!!